# Bootstrap OffCanvas not opening in deployed application

Tags: bootstrap-5

I have used bootstrap off-canvas in my vue project. It is working fine on local but when I deployed the project, the offcanvas is not opening what can be the possible reasons?

It is not working in any of the browsers. I have checked the code but it is working fine on the local system.